# How to Open WeChat Wallet from Another App in Swift

Tags: swift, wechat, wallet

I'm trying to open WeChat wallet from another app using this sample URL:

```
weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=sAmPlE88
```

with this code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=sAmPlE88")!)
```

But it's not working. What's currently working in that link is that it just opens the WeChat app in the previous view where the user left the WeChat app. How can I open WeChat Wallet from the WeChat app or even open the WeChat QR code scanner feature? Thanks in advance

Comment: I ma too having the same issue,  did you get any solution ? Please Share if any , thanks.

Comment: Sorry but no. I think WeChat needs to handle this feature.